# Is there a way of manually removing eclipse feature patch?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a problem with a feature patch jeopardizing an update of plugin it is patching. The thing is that the feature patch can't be uninstalled from inside of the eclipse. I wanted to ask if there is a way of removing it manually. I tried removing references of the patch from all files I found them inside the eclipse installation and the feature itself, but eclipse still somehow sees the feature patch in installation details. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with and update site containing the new product without the problematic feature patches